# Facebook authentication with deprecate_offline_access option

Tags: facebook, oauth

I ask for a Facebook access token with deprecate_offline_access turned on, and I get following response:

access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&expires=5183977

Does anybody know, what "expires" parameter means? It's value is not timestamp... 
I would like to know when the token expires, how could I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if "expires" is not a timestamp - it's probably not the number of milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970 UTC, but it could be (and probably is) a timestamp expressed in some means. I'd also like to know what it means.

Answer (score 0):

The "expires" parameter is just the time remaining from the time of request until the expiration time. It should be read as "expires in 5183977 seconds from time of request".

Comment: and what will I get if token is expired? will I get exception or just expired=0?

Answer (score 0):

5183977 seconds = 59.9997337962963 Days.

and answer to your last question 'what will I get if token is expired? will I get exception or just expired=0?'

you will get notification before token expire. If it is already expired (for mainly different reasons explained in facebook developer documentation) you have to re0auth the app and have to get new access token which will be again valid for next 60 days.